# Is there a way to run GAMS code (or other algebraic modeling language) from python?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gams-math

I've found this tutorial on a python API (https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_TUTORIAL.html), but it is unclear to me how it all works together. Specifically:

- do you build your model in GAMS, then run the .gms file from python?
- does the API translate the .gms file into python or do I have to model the problem using python code?

More generally - for someone familiar with GAMS, but limited python experience, are there any quick start sway to get up and running with optimization in python?

Comment: (1) Yes you can run a GMS file from Python (or store the GAMS model as a string in Python). (2) No. It basically allows you to "package" a GAMS model so that it can be executed from a Python environment (and manipulate the model or the data from Python). .